# Calling async method inside non async method python

Tags: python, asynchronous

```
import asyncio


async def asn1():
    print("asn1")
def sn():
    asyncio.run(asn1())


async def asn2():
    sn()


asyncio.run(asn2())
```

The above example code i have. But getting error while executing...
ERROR
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'asn1' was never awaited

Please suggest how to invoke a method from a async method where the invoked method is non async and inside it its invoking another async method.

Comment: In order for a function to be async, it must contain the `await` statement, otherwise, it's just any other function.

Comment: yes i understand @Cow. But here i have demonstrated a scenario that i have faced. If any other suggestion to resolve this then let me know.